# How to Select Rows of Pandas Dataframe with one Column Value which has multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, pandas-loc

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':['apple,guava','banana','orange'],'counts':[10,20,30]})
df.loc[df['Fruits']=='apple']

how can I get the count value as 10 with only one value i.e. apple ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us your code as a [mre].

Comment: is it better now ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you cannot get the count value with only one value "apple" as there is no such value present in your fruits column (you have guava and apple combined). You could split these two fruits into two separate column values, and get the count by:

```
df.iloc[row]['Fruits']
```

Where the row is where 'apple' is located.